# Как осуществить консольную команду в c++

Tags: c++, curl

Короче пишу программу под линукс. Я делаю запрос через curl скажите как мне ввести в терминал команду:
`curl http://url.com` . Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Используйте библиотеку libcurl.

Comment: Любая консольная команда выполняется с помощью функции `system("текст команды")`.

Comment: Если хотите моделировать из программы на С++ интерактивную работу с командой, то смотрите на [forkpty](https://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) или сразу на  [shellout](https://linux.die.net/man/3/shellout)